# Extend rand() max range

Tags: c++

I created a test application that generates 10k random numbers in a range from 0 to 250 000. Then I calculated MAX and min values and noticed that the MAX value is always around 32k...

Do you have any idea how to extend the possible range? I need a range with MAX value around 250 000!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is according to the definition of rand(), see:

http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/

http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/RAND_MAX/

If you need larger random numbers, you can use an external library (for example http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_random.html) or calculate large random numbers out of multiple small random numbers by yourself.

But pay attention to the distribution you want to get. If you just sum up the small random numbers, the result will not be equally distributed.

If you just scale one small random number by a constant factor, there will be gaps between the possible values.

Taking the product of random numbers also doesn't work.

A possible solution is the following:

```
1) Take two random numbers a,b
2) Calculate a*(RAND_MAX+1)+b
```

So you get equally distributed random values up to (RAND_MAX+1)^2-1

Comment: The product won't be linear either.  And your last solution should be `a * (RAND_MAX + 1) + b`.  (It will work for random values in the range `[0, (RAND_MAX+1)*(RAND_MAX+1))`, providing there's no overflow.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, you also want an equal distribution over this extended
range.  About the only way you can effectively do this is to generate a
sequence of smaller numbers, and scale them as if you were working in a
different base.  For example, for 250000, you might 4 random numbers
in the range [0,10) and one in range [0,25), along the lines:

```
int
random250000()
{
    return randomInt(10) + 10 * randomInt(10)
        + 100 * randomInt(10) + 1000 * randomInt(10)
        + 10000 * randomInt(25);
}
```

For this to work, your random number generator must be good; many
implementations of `rand()` aren't (or at least weren't—I've not
verified the situation recently).  You'll also want to eliminate the
bias you get when you map `RAND_MAX + 1` different values into `10` or
`25` different values.  Unless `RAND_MAX + 1` is an exact multiple of
`10` and `25` (e.g. is an exact multiple of `50`), you'll need something
like:

```
int
randomInt( int upperLimit )
{
    int const limit = (RAND_MAX + 1) - (RAND_MAX + 1) % upperLimit;
    int result = rand();
    while ( result >= limit ) {
        result = rand();
    return result % upperLimit;
}
```

(Attention when doing this: there are some machines where `RAND_MAX + 1`
will overflow; if portability is an issue, you'll need to take
additional precautions.)

All of this, of course, supposes a good quality generator, which is far
from a given.

Comment: Why not just make `randomInt` recursive if `upperLimit` is over RAND_MAX, and not bother with the needlessly slow `random250000()`?  (Or at _least_ give `randomInt` an `assert` to prevent invalid input.

Comment: @That's a possibility.  My goal wasn't to provide an optimal solution, but rather to suggest a workable approach; I chose `10` simply because everyone (I hope) is familiar with base 10 arithmetic, and would recognize the underlying idea.  Also: you have to watch out when `limit` in `randomInt` becomes large; you can end up throwing away a significant percentage of the results of `rand()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just manipulate your number bitwise by generating smaller random numbers.

For instance, if you need a 32-bit random number:

```
int32 x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) { // 4 == 32/8
   int8 tmp = 8bit_random_number_generator();
   x <<= 8*i; x |= tmp;
}
```

If you don't need good randomness in your numbers, you can just use rand() & 0xff for the 8-bit random number generator. Otherwise, something better will be necessary.

Comment: Actually, if `RAND_MAX` is of the form `2^n-1` (often the case), `rand() & 0xFF` will not introduce any bias.  (Of course, the way the implementation gets a `RAND_MAX` of this form may introduce bias.)

Comment: correct, but it's faster to use the `RAND_MAX` than any `8bit_random_number_generator`

Comment: You are both right, I was just pointing out a different implementation. If you use rand() at all, chances are you aren't going for really tight constraints, but you could of course need at least less run time.

The best solution is just to use a good external library like [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_random.html).

Comment: @MooingDuck Maybe.  If you end up throwing out a significant number of values returned from `rand()`, it might not be so fast.  And then, there's the problem of proving that your algorithm is reasonably correct.  At some point, you have to ensure that the number of values whatever the algorithm produces is an exact multiple of the number of values desired, or there will be some bias.

Answer (score 0):

Scale your numbers up by `N / RAND_MAX`, where `N` is your desired maximum. If the numbers fit, you can do something like this:

```
unsigned long long int r = rand() * N / RAND_MAX;
```

Obviously if the initial part overflows you can't do this, but with `N = 250000` you should be fine. `RAND_MAX` is 32K on many popular platforms.

More generally, to get a random number uniformly in the interval `[A, B]`, use:

```
A + rand() * (B - A) / RAND_MAX;
```

Of course you should probably use the proper C++-style `<random>` library; search this site for many similar questions explaining how to use it.

---

Edit: In the hope of preventing an escalation of comments, here's yet another copy/paste of the Proper C++ solution for truly uniform distribution on an interval `[A, B]`:

```
#include <random>

typedef std::mt19937 rng_type;
typedef unsigned long int int_type;  // anything you like

std::uniform_int_distribution<int_type> udist(A, B);
rng_type rng;

int main()
{
    // seed rng first:
    rng_type::result_type const seedval = get_seed();
    rng.seed(seedval);

    int_type random_number = udist(rng);
    // use random_number
}
```

Don't forget to seend the RNG! If you store the seed value, you can replay the same random sequence later on.

Comment: `(rand()*RAND_MAX+rand())/(RAND_MAX*RAND_MAX/250000);`?

Comment: The most frequent value of `RAND_MAX` is something like 2^31 (although obviously, that's not the case he's encountering).  And something like `rand() * N / RAND_MAX` will not give an equal distribution: without forcing anything to floating point, there will be a large number of holes, and even doing the intermediate calculations in floating point, then casting back to integer, you can never get more than `RAND_MAX` different values.

Comment: Your "more generally" algorithm doesn't generally work.  The probability that `rand() * (B - A)` overflows is large.  On my Linux box, it will overflow as soon a `(B - A) > 1`.  (Another problem is that you should be using `RAND_MAX + 1` everywhere, since that's the number of different values `rand()` can return.  Except, of course, that on my Linux box, `RAND_MAX + 1` overflows.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: That's all fine and well. Proper answers about `<random>` have been posted many times, which I mentioned, and this is nothing but a quick shot at a user who seems to be content with `rand()` for now. Everyone is invited to look up `<random>`.

Comment: @KerrekSB The advice about looking up `<random>` is good.  The standard `rand()` is often not particularly good.

Comment: @KerrekSB For the rest, his problem is getting random numbers in an interval greater than `[0,RAND_MAX]`.  There's no way a single call to `rand()` will do for that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using short ints? If so, you will see 32,767 as your max number because anything larger will overflow the short int.